# Assign Quintiles for each year in Panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, custom-function

Hi I got a panel data which contains 3 columns: `Firm`, `Year`, `Income`.

```
Firm <- rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"), each = 20)
Year <- rep(seq(1997, 2016, 1), times = 5)
Income <- rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 10)
df <- cbind(Firm, Year, Income)
```

The actual data contains more than 5000 firms and more than 50 years for each firm. But this is an good enough example to use.

I would like to assign quintile to the income for all the firms for EACH YEAR separately and put that in a new column called `Quint`.
For example, for year 1997, Firm `AAA` got income 50, Firm `BBB` got income 49, Firm `CCC` got income 48, Firm `DDD` got income 47, and Firm `EEE` got income 46. So Firm `AAA` got 1, `BBB` got 2, `CCC` got 3, `DDD` got 4, and `EEE` got 5, for 1997.

I have a custom function that does it for all the years but can't perform for EACH YEAR:

```r
quan <- function (x){
  y <-ifelse(x <= quantile(x, c(.2), na.rm = TRUE), 1,
        ifelse(x > quantile(x, c(.2), na.rm = TRUE) & x <= quantile(x, c(.4), na.rm = TRUE), 2,
          ifelse(x > quantile(x, c(.4), na.rm = TRUE) & x <= quantile(x, c(.6), na.rm = TRUE), 3,        
            ifelse(x > quantile(x, c(.6), na.rm = TRUE) & x <= quantile(x, c(.8), na.rm = TRUE), 4,
              ifelse(x > quantile(x, c(.8), na.rm = TRUE), 5, NA)))))
  y
}
```

How to do it for each year? Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use `cut` with `quantile` as breaks.   If we want to perform for each year, use `aggregate` or `data.table` or `dplyr` with 'Year' as grouping variable.  Also, create the `df <- data.frame(Firm, Year, Income)` and `aggregate(Income ~., df, quan)`

Comment: BTW, for each Firm, Year, combination, you have only a single observation.  So, if it is based on 'Year' as group only then `aggregate(Income ~Year, df, quan)`

Comment: Your code, `df <- cbind(Firm,Year,Income)`, creates a string matrix. This is not useful for what you want to do. Use `df <- data.frame(Firm,Year,Income)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use one of the group by functions here.  Using the OP's `quan` function, in `base R`, we can do `aggregate`

```
res <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(Income ~Year, df, quan))
```

---

Another option is to use `cut` with `breaks` as the `quantiles`

```
quan2 <- function(x) as.integer(cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, 
                   c(0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1)), include.lowest=TRUE))

res2 <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(Income ~Year, df, quan2))
all.equal(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Other alternatives include package solutions like `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.list(quan(Income)), by = Year]
```

Or `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Year) %>% 
    summarise(Income = list(quan(Income))) %>%
    unnest %>% 
    group_by(Year) %>% 
    mutate(ind = paste0("Income", row_number())) %>% 
    spread(ind, Income)
```

---

*Comments/Discussion*

1) The output of `aggregate` results in 'Income' column as a `matrix`, so we convert it to proper `data.frame` columns with `do.call(data.frame`.

2) Using `cbind` to create a dataset will result in a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only a single `class`.  If there is a any `character` value, the whole dataset will be converted to `character` matrix.  So, it is better to work on `data.frame` or `list` when the `class` of columns are different

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Firm, Year, Income)
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. But it pops en error:
arguments imply differing number of rows
I did a little research and it shows because the length of the companies are not the same. How do I do that?

Comment: res <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(Income ~Year, df, quan))
doesn't work when the companies don't have equal number of rows.
How do I solve that?

Comment: @Dylan  Have you tried the other solutions.  I am only looking at your example when I tested it

Comment: I tried the other two as well.
    setDT(df)[, as.list(quan(Income)), by = Year]
gives me a matrix instead of a vector which is what I need.

dplyr/tidyr version gives me error: 
: could not find function "unnest"

Comment: @Dylan Do you have the latest version of `tidyr`?

Comment: Yes I do have the latest version of tidyr. But it is giving me strange results. Is there any way to do it in base R? Aggregate can't work if every company doesn't have the same number of observations. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I do have the latest version or tidyr. 
So is there really no way to do it if the observation for each firm is different?
I would appreciate anybody that can figure it out.
Thanks.

Comment: @Dylan Please update your post with the example that gives the error as I am not able to reproduce error with this example

Comment: sure, let's just delete one row so that not every firm has the same number of observations.

    Firm <- rep(c("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE"), each=20)
    Year <- rep(seq(1997,2016,1),times=5)
    Income <- rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=10)
    df <- cbind(Firm,Year,Income)
    df <- as.data.frame(df)
    df <- df[!(df$Firm=="AAA" & df$Year=="2016"),]